# Converting unsigned char pointer of data to struct containing ints

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to cast this pointer of data to my `struct` and the actual value populate in the struct.

```
unsigned char *data = "00000001000000020000000300000004AE93KD93KD91Q830DMNE03KEkdaredgreenblueorangeyellow";

typedef struct mystruc {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} mystruc;

mystruct ms = (mystruct *)data;

printf("%i", ms->a);
```

Output:

```
808464432
```

I am trying to find out how to fill in `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` with the actual values 1, 2, 3, 4

I would like the output to be:

```
1
```

I will also need to later access the rest of the data.

Comment: `mystruct ms = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };`

Comment: `(mystruc *)data` should just be `(mystruc)*data`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sscanf()` to parse the numbers in the string.

```
mystruct ms;
sscanf(data, "%8d%8d%8d%8d", &ms.a, &ms.b, &ms.c, &ms.d);
```

`%8d` means to parse an 8-character decimal field as an `int`. If it's actually hexadecimal, change it to `%8x`.

Your code is interpreting the character codes in the string as the binary representation of the structure members, it doesn't parse it.

Comment: Aside, given 8 characters/`int`, I'd expect a hexadecimal input.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica OTOH, I'd expect unsigned int for hex fields.\

Comment: This worked perfectly. If I wanted to interpret my data as a short (1 byte) would it be ```%4d```?

Comment: The number after `%` is the number of characters in the string, not the size of the variable.

Answer (score -1):

Your `unsigned char` is one byte wide, so `"00000001"` will be `3030303031` in hex, because the ASCII code for `'0'` is `0x30` in hex, and the ASCII for `'1'` is `0x31`.

Your `int` is 4 bytes wide, so it'll capture the first 4 bytes of `data`, which will be `30303030` in hex, or `808464432` in decimal.

This, however, will work on a little-endian machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct mystruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
} mystruct;

unsigned char *data = "\1\0\0\0";  // use octal numbers, not ASCII, also note the reversed order

int main(void) {
 mystruct *ms = (mystruct *)data;

 printf("%i", ms->a); // outputs: 1
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the `unsigned char *` value in `data` (which points to a `char` array defined by a string literal) is correctly aligned for conversion to a `mystruct *`. Also, the example pointing to `"\1\0\0\0"` would output 1 on a little-endian machine, not a big-endian machine.

Comment: @IanAbbott, indeed, there's no guarantee about alignment. Fixed big-endian, thanks

Comment: There's no guarantee that an in is 4 bytes wide either.

Comment: @Christophe, indeed, and that's why I wrote "_your_ `int`" and "_your_ `unsigned char`". No guarantees, but it's important to understand why this particular code works this way, and not another.

Comment: Currently, you can't know if "your int" is 4 bytes.  This is implementation dependent and there's not trace of any evidence in OP's question.  Furthermore, your code might not work as expected on some architectures, and it might crash the programme on some other alignment-sensitive architectures.  This is undefined behavior and I think that no reader here should get the impression that this could be an acceptable way to go.

Comment: @Christophe, on the contrary, OP's `int` is exactly 4 bytes wide, because they got `808464432`, which is `0x30303030`, which are the first _four_ bytes of their string (otherwise they would've gotten `0x3030303031303030`, for example). It may not work on other architectures, that's why I said it works "on a little-endian machine". Of course, none of that is guaranteed, but the OP's output is explained like that, by the four leading bytes of their string _and_ their 4-byte wide `int` type. I'm not saying this is what should be done in this situation, I'm explaining why OP got this output.